# Where to run the 'main' script of a Dockercontainer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Pardon this more basic question. I'm working on Docker image whose sole purpose, when run, is to execute a script called ga_extract.R. I am confused about where I should run this command and how.

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
ADD install_packages.R /tmp/install_packages.R
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    less \
    vim  && \
      Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R && \
      rm -R /tmp/*
```

But as I understand it, Dockerfile is only related to the build of the container, i.e. set up? Would I try to run my Rscript within Dockerfile? Tried adding this line at the end, but nothing happened and the script did not execute `CMD Rscript ga_extract.R`

I also have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  ga_extract_marketing:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      start_date: "2020-11-13"
      start_date: "2020-11-13"
```

Would the convention be to run my rscript somewhere within docker-compose? I think that's what I want but am unsure how. I read some blogs about ENTRYPOINT Vs. CMD but I'm a bit uncertain.

If the whole purpose of running the container is to execute `ga_extract.R` with `Rscript ga_extract.R` once per day, what's the 'right' way to do this?

Note that the env variables in docker-compose, those two dates, are needed to run the R script. So order of operations wise, the script must be called during or after docker-compose is run?

I tried the following too:
In Dockerfile I added `ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript ga_extract.R"]` but this gave an error:

```
ERROR: for ga_extract_marketing  Cannot start service ga_extract_marketing: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"Rscript ga_extract.R\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

ga_extract.R is in the root directory. I also tried changing the entrypoint to `docker-entrypoint.sh` and then in `docker-entrypoint.sh` I put `Rscript ga_extract.R` but I got a similar error.

Even if the command was recognized, I'm unsure if it would work since I cannot tell if the env vars from docker-compose are set before the script runs. I run the container with:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

It's after running that last command I get the error.

More generally though, I'm just confused about the right way to approach this. How can I run the Rscript ga_extract.R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your entrypoint.

Try it like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "ga_extract.R"]
```

Environment variables should be picked-up at runtime.